# I am trying to install python-unitex however when doing the installing process I receive an error of: 'ld: library not found for -lunitex'

Tags: python, c++

This is the error I get when running the installation scripts. I cannot find any information online regarding -lunitex.

````
/usr/bin/clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-syslibroot,/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.5/extensions/_unitex.o -L/usr/local/lib -lunitex -o build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.5/_unitex.cpython-35m-darwin.so
ld: library not found for -lunitex
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang++' failed with exit status 1```
````

Comment: use the following command ```pip install --user -U pyunitex``` in cmd. You can also download it from https://pypi.org/project/pyunitex/

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this https://pypi.org/project/unitexlemmatizer/